# Fill png transparency with background color

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

I'm refactoring an old image crop/resize library i wrote about 5 years ago and i'm stuck trying to restore one of it's functionalities. The funny part is that i'm not even sure it worked back then since i probably never actually used it.

I need to be able to work on png images while keeping transparency (which works), but i also wan't to be able to fill the transparent part of the image with a color.

Creating a blank image and filling it with a color works fine, but when i try to paste my png over it, the background is transparent again.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
 <?php

$src = imagecreatefrompng($pathToSomePngFile);

imagealphablending($src, false);
imagesavealpha($src, true);

$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

if ($backgroundColor) {
    $fillColor = imagecolorallocate(
        $output, 
        $backgroundColor['r'], 
        $backgroundColor['g'], 
        $backgroundColor['b']
    );

    imagefilledrectangle(
        $output, 
        0, 
        0, 
        $width, 
        $height, 
        $fillColor
    );
} else {
    imagealphablending($output, false);
    imagesavealpha($output, true);
}

imagecopyresampled(
    $output,
    $src,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    $width,
    $height,
    $width,
    $height
);

imagepng($output, $pathToWhereImageIsSaved);
```

**UPDATE**

Updated with delboy1978uk's solution to get it to work without changing my other settings.

Comment: I was gonna say, create a new image with the background you want and copy the transparent one over it, but I see someone answered it already.

Comment: Yup, that's what i was doing before but it didn't work because of the imagealphablending and imagesavealpha settings. All i changed was adding the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
<?php

// open original image
$img = imagecreatefrompng($originalTransparentImage);
$width  = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

// make a plain background with the dimensions
$background = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$color = imagecolorallocate($background, 127, 127, 127); // grey background
imagefill($background, 0, 0, $color);

// place image on top of background
imagecopy($background, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

//save as png
imagepng($background, '/path/to/new.png', 0);
```

Comment: Your code did work, however i wanted to keep my settings for better output quality, so i digged a little more to check the differences between yours and mine. imagealphablending and imagesavealpha on the background resource were the culprit (doesn't seem to make a difference on the loaded png file). So i added a condition to only apply those filters when i don't want to use a background color et voilà, works like a charm now, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, have a great day!